# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'haystack.nodes'

Tags: google-colaboratory, nlp-question-answering, haystack

I am following the tutorial from haystacks website for Extractive QA system. I am trying to convert PDF to Text.
Link to the blog is here : (https://www.deepset.ai/blog/automating-information-extraction-with-question-answering)

I pip installed haystack but I get this error. I even tried !pip install haystack.nodes but that doesn't work.

Note: I am using Google Colab for this.

Here is my detailed code and error:

```
!pip -q install haystack haystack.nodes
path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/NLP/Information Extraction QA with Haystack (Adidas Financial corpus)'
from haystack.nodes import PDFToTextConverter

pdf_converter = PDFToTextConverter(remove_numeric_tables=True, valid_languages=['en'])

converted = pdf_converter.convert(file_path = path, meta = { 'company': 'Company_1', 'processed': False })
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-61021fb3b7b8> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from haystack.nodes import PDFToTextConverter
      2 
      3 pdf_converter = PDFToTextConverter(remove_numeric_tables=True, valid_languages=['en'])
      4 
      5 converted = pdf_converter.convert(file_path = path, meta = { 'company': 'Company_1', 'processed': False })
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Are you using the same python binary that is associated to the pip command?

Comment: Hello. Please follow the installation instructions in this tutorial, where `PDFToTextConverter` is used: https://haystack.deepset.ai/tutorials/08_preprocessing It should work

Comment: Also remember to install `farm-haystack` (not simply `haystack`).

Answer (score 1):

To install Haystack, you need to run `pip install farm-haystack`. The pypi package is called [farm-haystack](https://pypi.org/project/farm-haystack/) and not just haystack as Stefano mentioned.

A good starting point are the Haystack tutorials, which you can run as python notebooks on Google Colab, for example [this tutorial](https://haystack.deepset.ai/tutorials/08_preprocessing) using the PDFToTextConverter.

Answer (score 1):

Do not name any of your files haystack.py otherwise you will get import fails. This goes for all projects, never name any file like the library itself. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Note that installing `farm-haystack` and `haystack-ai` in the same Python environment (virtualenv, Colab, or system) causes problems. In my case, I had to enable the Telemetry environment.
These steps solved the problem for me:

```
!pip uninstall farm-haystack haystack-ai farm-haystack
!pip install --upgrade pip
!pip install farm-haystack[colab,ocr,preprocessing,file-conversion,pdf]
```

Then, I enabled the "Telemetry" environment by adding these lines at the top of my script:

```
from haystack.telemetry import tutorial_running
tutorial_running(8)
```